# Set Base Image, Small and Thumbnail to configurable products while images are already uploaded but not assigned

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I have lots of configurable products. Everything is working fine but the issue with product images. I have uploaded images to every configurable product but I forget to assign them as **Base Image** , **Small Images**, **Thumbnail** so that images are not visible to the frontend.

[image]

Could anyone please suggest me any easy way to assign images programmatically or any other way rather than assigning each image from admin panel because there are lots of configurable products?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to import the following CSV file to make images selected but still no success [CSV FILE](http://hemant.wcukdev.co.uk/test-product.csv)

Thank You!

Comment: You can assign images by import product csv with sku and images.

Comment: Thank You @SHPatel, Should I export the CSV first and then Import the same CSV ? or I have to make any changes in it?

Comment: You have to first export product csv file, edit csv file with delete all other fields and keep only sku with images field and then import it.

Comment: I have checked your csv which you have shared. can you tell me images path in your root folder. Working csv for me. I think there is just images path issue so share me images path so i will suggest to you for next use.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign images to product by import product csv.

Check below sample csv file for import sku with image, assing images to product.

[image]

Let me know if you have any query from above.

I hope it will help for you.

Comment: Shall I remove all other fields like category,  type and other configurable product options?

Comment: Yes you can remove all the fields. just inputed sku with images details.

Comment: Okay let me try.

Comment: For now I am trying with one product  but when I try to import by selecting import behavior "Replace Existing Complex Data" or any other option,  It gives me the error **Column names have duplicates**

Comment: Now error is fixed but still not showing the images in front-end after successful import.

Comment: Import behavior add/update data.

Comment: Check images first in admin.

Comment: Also clear cache / reindexing.

Comment: There is no option to add/update behavior. :(

Comment: In your case "Replace Existing Complex Data" is correct.

Comment: Still No Success Sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49214/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-sanchit-gupta).

Comment: I have checked your csv which you have shared. can you tell me images path in your root folder. Working csv for me. I think there is just images path issue so share me images path so i will suggest to you for next use.

Comment: Can you share images path with me ?

Comment: @SureshChikani Just assume i have no images file, them how can i solve this issue?